# Create new column by random sampling of other columns data

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to create a new column by randomly sampling data from the remaining columns.

Consider a dataframe with "N" columns as follows:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      Column 1       |     Column 2     |      Column N       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          0.37       |         0.8      |          0.0        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          0.0        |         0.0      |          0.8        |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

The resulting dataframe should look like

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------|
|      Column 1       |     Column 2     |      Column N       |     Sampled   |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------|
|          0.37       |         0.8      |          0.0        |       0.8     |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------|
|          0.0        |         0.0      |          B          |        B      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------|
|          A          |         5        |          0.8        |        A      |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------|
```

The "Sampled" column's entries are created by randomly choosing one of the corresponding entries of the "N" columns. For example, "0.8" was chosen from Column 2, "B" from Column N, and so on.

`df.sample(axis=1)` simply chooses one column and returns it. This is NOT what I want.

What would be the fastest way to achieve this? The method needs to be efficient as the original dataframe is big with lots of rows and columns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pandas base `lookup` + `sample`

```
s=df.columns.to_series().sample(len(df),replace = True)
df['New']=df.lookup(df.index,s)
df
Out[177]: 
  Column1  Column2 ColumnN  New
0    0.37      0.8     0.0  0.8
1     0.0      0.0       B    B
2       A      5.0     0.8    A
```

Comment: Note that [lookup has been deprecated](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) in pandas v1.2.0 and one should use [`melt`+`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-lookup) instead.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the underlying `numpy` array and select a random index per row.

```
u = df.values
r = np.random.randint(0, u.shape[1], u.shape[0])

df.assign(Sampled=u[np.arange(u.shape[0]), r])
```

```
  Column 1  Column 2 Column N Sampled
0     0.37       0.8      0.0    0.37
1      0.0       0.0        B       B
2        A       5.0      0.8       A
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to `apply` `np.random.choice` to to the dataframe, along the rows. This may or may not give you the performance you require, but I leave that up to you to decide

Setup: DF with 4 columns, 11000 rows

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[np.random.rand() for i in range(11000)],'b':[np.random.rand() for i in range(11000)],
                 'c':[np.random.rand() for i in range(11000)],'d':[np.random.rand() for i in range(11000)]})

%timeit df['e']=df.apply(lambda x: np.random.choice(x), axis=1)

193 ms ± 28 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Additional benchmarks:

Adding `x.values` into the lambda appears to improve the speed by approximately 20%. However, @wen-ben's solution is a 100-fold improvement on this method on the same dataframe

```
1.91 ms ± 155 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

By request, here is the timing for user3483203's answer, may be even better (I had to do some things to it to make it work with the timing magic, so ymmv)

```
%%timeit
df1=df.copy()
u = df.values
r = np.random.randint(0, u.shape[1], u.shape[0])

df1=df1.assign(Sampled=u[np.arange(u.shape[0]), r])

590 µs ± 37 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: would you like test the lookup method timing ?

Comment: Yeah, you definitely win!

Comment: @G.Anderson Thank you for timing all the methods!

Comment: @HarshavardhanRamanna you are very welcome! `%timeit/%%timeit` are very useful ipython magic functions to know of and become familiar with, especially if you use jupyter notebooks for testing.

Comment: Mind adding the timings for mine?

Comment: Wow, `df.assign` _really_ doesn't like to play well with `%%timeit` haha! That said, I think we have a winner. Editing now.

Comment: Assign should work with timeit, it doesn't modify the dataframe, but returns a copy, it works for me in IPython.  Also, in your test code, you make a copy of the DataFrame, but still use `df.values` for `u`, which seems to defeat the purpose of making a copy.

Comment: Without the `df.copy`, for some reason it threw a `reference before assignment` error. No idea why!

Answer (score 2):

```
from random import choice
df['sample'] =  df.apply(lambda x:choice(x.values),axis =1)
```

Comment: You solution with `.values` improves on my efficiency by approximately 30ms on my dataset, nice!