# Create new column by sampling bits of other columns

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the dataframe containing N columns as shown below. Each entry is an 8-bit integer.

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|      Column 1       |     Column 2     |      Column N       |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          4          |         8        |          13         |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
|          0          |         32       |          16         |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|
```

I'd like to create a new column with 8-bit entries in each row by randomly sampling each bit of data from the remaining columns. So, the resulting dataframe would look like:

```
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------|
|      Column 1       |     Column 2     |      Column N       |     Sampled   |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------|
|      4 = (100)      |     8 = (1000)   |    13 = (1101)      |   5 = (0101)  |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------|
|      0 = (0)        |    32 = (100000) |   16 = (10000)      | 48 = (110000) |
|---------------------|------------------|---------------------|---------------|
```

The first entry in the "sampled" column was created by selecting one bit among all possible bits for the same position. For example, the LSB=1 in the first entry was chosen from `{0 (LSB from col 1), 0 (LSB from col 2), 1 (LSB from col N)}`, and so on.

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55598225/create-new-column-by-random-sampling-of-other-columns-data) but instead of each entry being sampled, each bit needs to be sampled.

What is an efficient way of achieving this, considering the dataframe has a large number of rows and columns? From the similar question, I assume we need a `lookup` + `sample` to choose the entry and another `sample` to choose the bits?

Comment: I have a method to achieve that but slow, how big is your data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same logic like before when you do the sample , but here I convert between the binary and decimal twice, with [unnesting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53218931/how-do-i-unnest-explode-a-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe) , then join back the result

```
df1=df.applymap(lambda x : list('{0:08b}'.format(x)))

df1=unnesting(df1,df1.columns.tolist())
s=np.random.randint(0, df1.shape[1], df1.shape[0])

yourcol=pd.Series(df1.values[np.arange(len(df1)),s]).groupby(df1.index).apply(''.join)

df['Sampled']=yourcol.map(lambda x : int(x,2))

df
Out[268]: 
   c1  c2  cn  Sampled
0   4   8  13       12
1   0  32  16       16
```

---

```
def unnesting(df, explode):
    idx = df.index.repeat(df[explode[0]].str.len())
    df1 = pd.concat([
        pd.DataFrame({x: np.concatenate(df[x].values)}) for x in explode], axis=1)
    df1.index = idx

    return df1.join(df.drop(explode, 1), how='left')
```